# Elasticsearch: what is the proper way to use copy_to with a child object

Tags: elasticsearch

Given a schema like the following:

```
{
  "id": {"type": "keyword"},
  "subjects": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {"type": "keyword"},
      "name": { "type": "keyword" }
      "name_search": { "type": "text" }
    }
  }
}
```

How does one properly use "[copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/copy-to.html)" to copy from name to name_search given you may have more than one item in subject?

I think you can do, "copy_to": "subjects.name_search", but does this mean that the copy stays within the child document?

i.e.

```
{id: 123, subjects: [ {id:1, name: "Art"}, {id:2, name: "History"}}
```

becomes:

```
{
  id: 123, subjects: [ 
   {id:1, name: "Art", name_search:"Art"}, 
   {id:2, name: "History", name_search:"History"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: To clarify a bit "Nested Document" is an Elasticsearch concept for the "Nested datatype". Your mapping does not present a nested datatype, so I am a bit unsure of how to answer "does this mean that the copy stays within the nested document"

Comment: @IanGabes Apologies for having my terminology a bit inexact. I will change it to "child" as it's more accurate.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, no, the copy does not stay within the child document. Arrays are a bit surprising in ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html